# How to customize Azure DevOps WorkItem Field Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for a way to add an additional column for test steps in Azure DevOps TestCase WorkItem.

It is possible to add new fields (string / select controls etc) and reorder existing fields on the test case level. But is it possible to customize the Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps Field?

There is no possibility to adapt it in the test case edit view
[image: process edit view]

and the field delete / edit in all fields area is deactivated too
[image]

In the self hosted azure devops server 2019 it seems to be possible over tfs power tools / wit export & import. But how to do it in the azure cloud? maybe there is a way over extensions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using [XML process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019) in azure devops server 2019. But in azure devops service, you are using [inherited processes model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process). To customize work item types in inherited processes, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-wit?view=azure-devops

You can only delete the custom fields, those fields defined for system processes can not be deleted. `Steps` is a particular field that can not be hide. If you want to customize `Steps` field, you would need to create a custom work item and customize the `Steps` field there.

Comment: thank you for your reply. New WorkItem would work as well, but i still want to use the possibility to organize and execute the testcases in azure testplan and use all the features of Teststeps (like Shared Steps, Test Data Parameter etc). I just need one column more with additional data for each step row. Is it possible to use the Steps Field and extend /inherite it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it can not be achieved currently.